# Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection, how to prove that $\exists N\forall n \ N\leq n\implies f(n)\geq n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection, how to prove that $\exists N\forall n \ N\leq n\implies f(n)\geq n$?

this is very intuitive, i tried to prove it using contradiction, assume $\forall N\exists n\ N\leq n\wedge f(n)<n$. but then i'm stuck, i'd appreciate any hint on how to proceed

Comment: Consider the sequence $2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9, \ldots$. This does not satisfy your lemma

Comment: This seems to be clearly false.  What did you mean to ask?

Comment: OP might have missed out the condition that $f$ is order-preserving.

Comment: @ClementYung The identity is the only order-preserving bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider $f(n) = n+1$ if $n$ is even and $n-1$ is $n$ is odd.

Comment: my bad, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Are you sure you gave us all the hypothesis ? Have a look at @ClementYung comment

Comment: affirmative $ \ \ $

Answer (score 2):

You *don't* prove it, since it is false. Take, for instance,$$f(n)=\begin{cases}n+1&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\n-1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$